# Conditions on Quotient maps and local connectedness

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a compact connected Hausdorff metric space. It is known that $Y$ is a quotient of $X$ and $f: X \to Y$ is the quotient map. Finally it is also known that $Y$ is a compact, connected, locally connected, Hausdorff metric space.

Under what conditions on $f$ can we conclude $X$ is also locally connected?

It is known that quotients of locally connected spaces are locally connected. Usually the converse is not true. I want to know if there are any theorems or hypothesis under which partial converse is possible.

In particular I am interested in the case when the quotient process is identifying discrete pairs of points in $X$ . Moreover it is known that these pairs of points are cut-pairs (removing any pair of points disconnects $X$) and the collection is null (for any e>0, there are only finitely many pairs outside any ball of radius e). Under these hypothesis if $Y$ is locally connected, then is $X$ locally connected?

A little bit more generally I am interested to know that if pre-images of $Y$ in $X$ under are discrete or finite or compact (or satisfy some other finiteness condition) then can we say something about the local connectedness of $X$?

Comment: You have to be more specific to get helpful answers. One easy sufficient condition is to have $f: X\to Y$ a fiber bundle with locally connected fibers. But, likely, this assumption is too strong for you.

Comment: Moishe thank you for the comment. In particular I am interested in the case when the quotient process is identifying discrete pairs of points in X. Moreover it is known that these pairs of points are cut-pairs (removing them disconnects X) and null (for any e>0, there are only finitely many pairs outside any ball of radius e). I guess this is too specific. May be one can ask that if pre-images of Y are discrete or finite or compact (or some other finiteness condition) then can we say something about the local connectedness of X.

Comment: This is better, but what do you mean by "discrete pairs"? This terminology is totally nonstandard.

Comment: Here ‘discrete’ means that the collection of pairs of points are  translates of a pair of point by a finitely generated group (in my specific case, the group is known to have a geometrically finite convergence action on the space X)